# Limiting external process resources programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, sandbox

I'm developing a .NET application, which have a 3rd party plugins. These plugins comes as EXE files, which works with application APIs and data.

Due to security concerns, I would like to be able "sandbox" them, when they're launched through my application. Especially, the most important is to be able to limit access to the drives or directories of filesystem.

**Is there any way to do this through [AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161678/net-new-process-sandbox-for-untrusted-code)? Or in any other way?**

Also some external plugins may not be written in managed code as my software exposes APIs to COM, but it is possible to drop non .NET plugin support. The more important thing for us is to sandbox those plugins.

Any way to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3242002/2183287

Comment: You cannot sandbox an external process.  The process isolation boundary is already a pretty decent guarantee that it cannot poke around in your process.  Running it with a limited user account that is not in the Everyone group would be next.  Ask questions about that at a site like serverfault.com

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I found the AppDomain way and the link Ronaldo sent. My question really is, if with AppDomain can we restrict application only to specific directories on filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you need to do this for a process that's not (necessarily) entirely based on .NET, `AppDomain`s probably won't be adequate for the task.

I'd consider running the processing inside a Windows [Job Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx). This lets you set up a sandbox that limits the process' use of things like the CPU and memory.

Access to the file system is already handled based on user accounts using Discretionary Access Control Lists ([DACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446597.aspx)s). To limit access to a few specific parts of the file system, set up an account to use to run the sandboxed jobs, and set up access-allowed ACEs for the parts of the file system they're allowed to use. If you need to support more than one user running sandboxed jobs, you might want to set up a user group for the sandboxed jobs, and associate the ACEs with the group instead of the individual users.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Jerry. I think, that it's really near to perfect solution for my answer. Actually, I see this problem in your approach: To make the example fully understandable, let's assume, that my plugin is excel.exe and it should be allowed to see c:\allowed folder only. If I create new Windows account, I have to modify whole file system permissions to deny access to all folders, excepting the c:\allowed due to default configurations of permission on Windows. That's not acceptable to do on client machines. Am I correct or I missed something?